# Naming conflict between two classes from my project and a pod

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift4

Is there a way the solve class naming conflicts between two different classes coming from my project and a pod framework ?

I think the best solution would be that my project use its own Product class by default unless if I write `Tracker.Product`.

**Bit of context...**

In my project, I have an Objective-C class:

```
@interface Product : DatabaseObject { /* ... */ }
```

The framework I want to use declares:

```
public class Product : BusinessObject { /* ... */ }
```

The problem is that as soon as I import the library in one of my Swift file, like this:

```
import Tracker
```

**The error...**

I get this error in my Swift files which try to use the `Product : DatabaseObject`

[image]

I guess there is a conflict between the 2 names but it is strange because I have this error in every swift file using Product, even the ones without no `import Tracker`.

**What I tried**

- Rename one class: it works but bad/sad solution
- Change Framework class to `internal`: cannot work because it exposes public methods using this class type
- Found that it is possible to `typealias` the import as described in [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID351) but didn't manage to make it work for my case

**Extra question**... *(insatiable curiosity)*

- Do you know why the `import Tracker` is impacting all other swift files ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't understand the question. You know you have a name clash. You know you can solve it by resolving through the use of the module as a namespace. Swift has namespaces, for this very reason. (Objective-C has no namespaces, another good reason for using Swift instead.) So... What's the problem?

Comment: As soon as I write `import Tracker` it causes errors everywhere in my code where I want to use my own implementation of `Product`

Comment: @matt Obviously I would prefer using swift only but sometimes we just cannot make the move. Still, for me it seems to be a serious namespacing question with real problems of languages cohabitation. I don't understand the downvote and the ask for close.

Comment: I have the same problem with you but I declare `class Product : BusinessObject { /* ... */ }` without `public` seem even without public the class got expose somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your extra question…

Swift namespaces are by module. Once you bring the name `Product` in from `Tracker` in one file the name exists in the whole module. (Though for some reason you still have to import external modules into each file that you want to actually use the module in, I have no idea why that is…)

Now for your issue of the two `Product` names colliding…

The tradition with Objective-C classes is to put a three letter prefix on them. This has always been done because there is only one namespace in Objective-C. With only one namespace the odds that there will be multiple version of `Product` becomes extremely high. Two letter prefixes are reserved by Apple which is why you see things like `NSString`, `UIViewController`, etc. Apple uses "NS" or an abbreviation from the framework's name for all of their prefixes. Individual developers and companies have traditionally used their own initials, company initials, or in the case of frameworks and libraries an abbreviation of the corresponding name.

Since the class you are having collision issues with is an Objective-C class the easiest thing to do is follow tradition and stick a prefix on it. It isn't very Swift-like but it isn't a Swift class, it's an Objective-C class…

Comment: Wow, your response is incredibly precise! You just taught me so many things. I will probably rename my ObjC conflicting classes. All that said, I still don't understand why the swift class `Product` under the module `Tracker` haven't an ObjC generated name like `TrackerProduct`. It would be like "emulating" namespaces for ObjC.

Comment: "I still don't understand why the swift class Product under the module Tracker haven't an ObjC generated name" You can _give_ it an ObjC name. Use the `@objc(...)` attribute.

Comment: If I go further in my reasoning with another case... if both Framework A & Framework B implement a swift `public class Product` and I import them in an ObjC project. Both of their `-Swift.h` headers will contain an `@interface Product` and then... bim, names colliding ?

Comment: @matt thanks, I know that feature but I was talking about something more automatic, why wouldn't the objc name be prefixed by the swift namespace by default? I guess it would avoid unnecessary conflict.

Comment: It is prefixed by the Swift namespace _in Swift_.